# PYTHON: Why does "varaible=float(variable)/len(variable2)" work, but "variable=float(variable) variable/len(variable2)" does not work?

Tags: python, dictionary

```
lloyd = {
  "name": "Lloyd",
  "homework": [90.0, 97.0, 75.0, 92.0],
  "quizzes": [88.0, 40.0, 94.0],
  "tests": [75.0, 90.0]
{

alice = {
  "name": "Alice",
  "homework": [100.0, 92.0, 98.0, 100.0],
  "quizzes": [82.0, 83.0, 91.0],
  "tests": [89.0, 97.0]
}

tyler = {
  "name": "Tyler",
  "homework": [0.0, 87.0, 75.0, 22.0],
  "quizzes": [0.0, 75.0, 78.0],
  "tests": [100.0, 100.0]
}

# Add your function below!
def average(numbers):
  total=sum(numbers)
  total=float(total)
  total/len(numbers)
  return total
print total

test = lloyd['homework']

average(test)`
```

When I test for the average, it does not come back the same as varaible=float(variable)/len(variable2)

Sorry for the bad format I'm new

Comment: `total/len(numbers)` does nothing. Do you mean `total/=len(numbers)` ? _that_ would work

Comment: `total/len(numbers)` you are not storing this result (which is what you want).

Answer (score 1):

You should return `total/len(numbers)`.  As it is, you calculate the average, but then don't do anything with that value, so it is discarded.

```
def average(numbers):
    total=sum(numbers)
    total=float(total)
    avg = total/len(numbers)
    print(avg)
    return avg
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: If i wanted to print the total, would I put `print total/len(numbers)` in the line under the return line?

Comment: No.  When a function returns, the program exits the function entirely.  It would never reach the return.  To print the average and return it, you would assign the average to a variable `avg = total/len(numbers)` and then print it and then return it